# How do I store images into UIImage array (Swift)

Tags: swift, parse-platform, uiimage, pffile

Here is my code

```
self.pages?.photo1.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (imageData: NSData?, error:NSError?) -> Void in
                if error == nil {
                    let image = UIImage(data: imageData!)
                    println(image!)
                    self.pageImages.append(image!)
```

when I run a `println(pageImages.count)`  I get a 0 even though I know there are other elements in my dataset (pages)

NOTE: "photo1" is stored in a dictionary as a PFFIle type

and a println(image) displays the following result

**UIImage: 0x7f90f3e12df0, {748, 420}}**

Comment: How do you declare `pageImages`? Why are you just setting/replacing the first element?

Comment: here is the delcaration  var pageImages: [UIImage] = []

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. You should not correct your own question. For the benefit of others, please revert it to your original question and accept the answer instead.

Comment: It is still my original question even after implementing the changes I am not able to get any data into  **pageImages** array

Comment: It works for me in Playground. The error must be somewhere else (perhaps you are trying the `arrayName[0] = value` pattern elsewhere?).

Comment: May be it has something to do with the file type?   image reference is stored as a PFFILE type and I am using 'getDataInBackgroundWithBlock' to download the image and assign it to  **pageImages** array

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you cannot add an element to an array the way you did.

To add an element at the end, use

```
pageItems.append(image)
```

To insert an element at the beginning, use

```
pageItems.insert(image, atIndex: 0)
```

The following works as expected in Playground:

```
var imageArray: [UIImage] = []
let image = UIImage()
imageArray.append(image)
imageArray.insert(image, atIndex: 0)
let x = imageArray.count               // 2
```